# Choose Controller Bean instance by RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want Spring to create 2 instances of FooController. Requests to /foo should be handled by one of the instances and requests to /bar should be handled by the other instance. I want something like the below, but of course `@RequestMapping` doesn't work that way and also Spring gives me the ambiguous mapping error on FooController as well.

```
@RestController
public class FooController {
  String name;
  public FooController(String name) { this.name = name; }
}

@Configuration
public class FooControllerConfig {
  @Bean
  @RequestMapping("/foo")
  public FooController getFooFooController(){
    return new FooController("foo");
  }
  @Bean
  @RequestMapping("/bar")
  public FooController getBarFooController(){
    return new FooController("bar");
  }
}
```

Comment: In Spring, you don't map URIs to beans, but to methods instead. Besides, controllers are singleton instances, meaning there is only one instance of each controller class (I guess you might have more than one instance per class, but it seems pointless)

Comment: I was bored, and this sounded interesting.  I don't know why you'd want to, but you can have multiple instances of the same controller class, each of which handles a different  URL through the same or a different method in the controller.  The only thing is, I don't know how to do it with just annotations.  The way I just did it was to dynamically register each request mapping at initialization time.  The FooController becomes a prototype bean (defined with annotations) so you can have Spring instantiate it multiple times, once for each mapping.  I'll post what I did if you're interested.

Comment: That sounds promising @Steve! If it's not too much work to share, I'd appreciate seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try this at home.  This code was performed by a bored, trained professional...

You can have multiple instances of the same controller class, each of which handles a different URL through the same or a different method in the controller. The only thing is, I don't know how to do it with just annotations. The way I just did it was to dynamically register each request mapping at initialization time. The FooController becomes a prototype bean (defined with annotations) so you can have Spring instantiate it multiple times, once for each mapping

**FooController.java**

```
@Controller
@Scope("prototype")
public class FooController {

    private String name;

    public FooController() {}

    public FooController(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ResponseEntity<String> handleRequests() throws Exception {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Yo: " + name + " " + this.hashCode(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**EndpointService.java**

```
@Service
public class EndpointService {

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping;

    public void addFooController(String urlPath, String name) throws NoSuchMethodException {

        RequestMappingInfo requestMappingInfo = RequestMappingInfo
                .paths(urlPath)
                .methods(RequestMethod.GET)
                .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();

        requestMappingHandlerMapping.registerMapping(requestMappingInfo,
                beanFactory.getBean(FooController.class, name),
                FooController.class.getDeclaredMethod("handleRequests"));
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefreshEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent ctxStartEvt) {
        try {
            addFooController("/blah1", "blahblah1");
            addFooController("/blah2", "blahblah2");
            addFooController("/blah3", "blahblah3");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
http://localhost:8080/blah1 returns: Yo: blahblah1 1391627345

http://localhost:8080/blah3 returns: Yo: blahblah3 2078995154
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I was hoping there was some slightly more intuitive way, but this definitely helps me understand the workings of manually adding request handlers. I appreciate you taking the time to write this up!

Comment: Glad I could be helpful!  Yeah...this is not quite "intuitive", is it?  I'd call it downright ugly and confuscating.  But if you had a reason why you really had to do this, you could comment the heck out of this to explain what it's doing and why.  Do you have such a need, or is this just an academic exercise at this point?

Comment: I don't need this in a business setting, no. I was just trying to make some demo code for a presentation on how you can inject your own service beans in a `@Configuration` class, but the example worked best if I could also then give pass each Service bean to a copy of the same controller, so you can say here's one controller with a Service configured one way, and here's a copy with it configured a different way. But since you can't register the same endpoints to two different services, there was no way to demonstrate using it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really confused by why you need this requirement? Can you please explain why this is required? Is it that each mapping requires a different name?

First you do not map Beans to a RequestMapping. While I am not even sure the spring application would start it would potentially create a new Bean with an identical name every time you access one of these mappings which would probably throw an error.

You could potentially overcome the duplicate names with your own annotation processing but that is way more work then this looks like it is worth.

Just looking at what you have there is there any reason why the following will not meet your requirements?

```
@RestController
public class FooController {

    private static final fooName = "fooName";
    private static final barName = "barName";

    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    public String getFoo(){
        return fooName;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/bar")
    public String getBar(){
      return barName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Say for example my class FooController has 10 methods on it, and those methods use a FooService to do some logic in a particular way. I could access those methods using a series of endpoints like /foo/dothing1/param1 and /foo/dothing2/param2/param3 and so on. I want to reuse the entire set of endpoints to return exactly the same results, except if the path begins with /bar, then do the calculations with a BarService instead. I gave my controllers a string here, but in actual implementation, they each have a different ServiceImpl.

Comment: In that instance could you not have an Abstract FooBar class with an abstract property for your Service (as an Interface). Both of your services would then implement this interface. You would have FooController extends FoobarController and BarController extends FoobarController and designate the specific mapping of "foo" at the top level right under the @Controller() annotation. Then each controller has the proper instance of the service implementation wired in?